# Почему так стремятся превратить ru.stackoverflow в тень stackoverflow в "культурном плане"

Tags: обсуждение, закрытие-вопросов

Столкнулся с таким фактом ненависти к новичкам.

**Stack Overflow на русском** превращается в Stack Overflow, где новичков ненавидят, **где  новичок должен прыгать вокруг старожилов**, абы не обидеть   этим мудрецов.

*Я конечно понимаю, множество людей, здесь "сидящих", живут на западе. Многие выращены в западных традициях, но я не хочу и не желаю чтобы наша культура превращалась в "тень" их культуры.*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: День добрый. Я постарался поправить ваше сообщение, чтобы оно было не настолько агрессивно настроенным.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica спасибо :3

Comment: Извините, но что вы вкладываете в "наша культура"? "Наша" - это чья?

Comment: @PashaPash РФ :3

Comment: Сколики людям помогли конкретно вы? Не просто помогли, а уделили 2-3 часа вопросу, написали ответ, всё продумали? Максимум - спасибо, хорошо, а ещё веселее если скажут - а не подходит. Думаю надо различать где помощь, а где работа. Зачем студенту решать задачу, если он текст задачи вобьет в SO, а утром скопирует себе ответ и забудет. Слава растёт - "студентов" становится больше. Завтра 1000 вопросов будет от "студентов". Каждый по разу задаст вопрос, получит ответ. А база знаний.... пуста. А вопросов такого характера становится становится больше.

Comment: @timob256 "StackOverflow на русском" != "Российский StackOverflow". Лично я не принадлежу к культуре РФ, как и многие другие участники, и для меня нападки на "запад" и призывы защищать культуру РФ силами участников SO выглядят довольно дико.

Comment: это не является ненавистью или агрессией или русской культурой, это просто борьба с халявщиками. С вопросами, которые никому не нужны кроме самого халявщика. Может вам есть смысл побыть пол-года робин-гудом... думаю на больше вас не хватит.

Comment: @nick_n_a вы сейчас исходите из предположения, что такая "борьба" хоть немного эффективна. Но по факту - 99% таких вопросов - от аккаунтов - однодневок, которым все равно на минусы, закрытия и баны. Минусуйте, не минусуйте, закрывайте, не закрывайте - такие вопросы все равно рано или поздно снесет бот, просто по неактивности. Минусы только чуть ускорят процесс.

Comment: @timob256 вы не могли бы более конкретно выразиться и пояснить что именно вы считаете проблемным в недавних изменениях на сайтах? Что вы имеете ввиду под "западными" и "русскими" традициями в контексте пользования сетью сайтов StackExchange?

Comment: Какая еще ненависть к новичкам? Вы тут постите вопросы уже больше года (а зарегистрировались вообще 5+ лет назад, судя по профилю), уже не новичок. И западную культуру зачем-то приплели... Вам отсыпали минусов за качество вопроса, и все.

Answer (score 19):

На мой взгляд - как ни к стати новичка - отношение к новичкам *SO на русском* вполне *приемлемое*.

Зарегистрирован я около 100 дней, за это время особых придирок или ненависти к себе я не наблюдал, были правки, были опровержения сопровождающиеся дискуссией в комментариях, но все они были по делу, действительно в некоторых моментах я ошибался. И если кто-то воспринимает критику к своему вопросу или ответу негативно, то это вероятнее всего **не правильное отношения новичка к сообществу**, а не наоборот.

Изначально целью посещать данный ресурс решил для своего развития, зная ошибки с которыми сталкиваются *пользователи/администраторы/программисты*(нужное подчеркнуть) становится легче понять направление для углубленного изучения/саморазвития.

После появления доступа к очереди проверок, начал замечать что примерно 30% из увиденных мной вопросов - это **"ПАМАГИТИ ПРАГРАМА НИ КАМПИЛИРУЕТСЯ, ХАЧУ СОЗДАТЬ ИГРУ, НО АНА НИ РАБОТАЕТ"**, естественно, даже у меня **не** "старожила" ресурса появляется негативное отношение к подобным сообщениям, ведь они мешают в первую очередь мне.

Comment: Так это вы домашку не постили. Не знаю, 30% халявщиков или больше/меньше, но к таким отношение резко отрицательное.

Comment: @AK примерно эту же мысль хотел расписать в ответе, изначальное непонимание цели сообщества у прибывших участников.

Answer (score 16):

В любом обществе есть свои порядки. На этом сайте они подчиняются основной цели: накапливать и передавать знания.

От новых и старых участников мы ждём одного и того же: задавать толковые вопросы, давать понятные и полезные ответы, в процессе уважать друг друга и всех читателей.

На скриншоте я вижу столкновение двух культур, в которых по-разному понимают слово "помощь". В культуре А помощь — это когда человек четко формулирует запрос, принимает помощь и сам отвечает за результат. А культуре Б помощь — когда человек снимает с себя ответственность и задачу решают за него.

Я себя отношу к культуре А, и я ей научился здесь. Если я задаю вопрос коллеге по работе, я точно объясняю, в чём моя задача, прихожу с вариантами решения, отвечаю на дополнительные вопросы. Просто кинуть проблему, обижаться на вопросы, обвинять и агриться — непрофессионально и неуважительно.

Никакой "западной" и "нашей" культуры тут нет. Уважение и ответственность за себя — ценности общечеловеческие.

Comment: А под термином `полезные` вы имеете ввиду [такие](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1039845/256824)?

Comment: @РустамГимранов плохо знаю JS, не могу оценить полезность ответа. А по-вашему, что с этим ответом?

Comment: Ответ, как ответ, все нормально. Хотел лишь уточнить, что по-вашему является `полезным ответом`, и привел в качестве примера..

Comment: @РустамГимранов если судить по объективным критериям, то полезность оценивается по числу голосов и наличию галочки на ответе.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica, а помимо "объективных" критериев какие-то еще существуют? То есть имеются еще и "субъективные", то есть все зависит от того, кем он оставлен?

Comment: @РустамГимранов конечно. Вот в контексте [tag:javascript], представим, что у нас бы была секта тех, кто минусует посты, где код не использует es6 фишки. Они бы руководствовались явно субъективными принципами.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica, а как вы относитесь к тому, что сам вопрос, на которой был дан этот [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1039845/256824) является дубликатом?

Comment: @РустамГимранов дубликаты нужно закрывать (:

Comment: @РустамГимранов полезность — это примерно количество человек, которым ответ помог решить их задачу, помноженное на сложность задачи. Количество пропорционально голосам на ответе, сложность обратно пропорциональна (сложные задачи реже встречаются).

Comment: @NickVolynkin, интересные формулы, но я как-то ожидал увидеть пример полезного ответа. Я уже нашел https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/431521/256824, спасибо.

Answer (score 7):

1. Мифические "культуры" тут вообще не при чём. Как минимум, потому что на сайте люди сидят со всех уголков мира. Даже если говорить про русскоговорящие страны, то тут есть люди и из России, и из Беларуси, и с Украины.
2. Многие по ошибке считают (это, кстати, вероятно, из-за нашего слогана "сайт вопросов и ответов"), что Stack Overflow - это нечто вроде "Ответов Mail.ru". Нет, это не так.
3. Это всё про уважение. Нужно при оформлении вопроса руководствоваться своими ожиданиями от ответа.

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: С Украины или из Украины?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ не знаю, честно говоря. Всю жизнь применяю **с**. Если знаете как грамматически правильно, можете поправить.

Comment: Если все же **многие считают**, так может и вправду признать, что мы сайт вопросов и ответов (и пусть *некоторые желающие* создают из них свою *базу знаний*)

Comment: @avp может и стоит)

Answer (score 5):

Не надо всё мешать в одну кучу.

1. С новичками проблем не вижу, адекватным новичкам тут вполне рады, даже вплоть до [такого](//chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=52291109#52291109). Не рады попыткам сбросить полностью домашку на сообщество, но вроде это вполне логично - решать одни и те же учебные примеры никому не интересно. [Ну и ответ в тему.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9634/178988)
2. Про культуру согласен. На мой взгляд, стараются зря. Но надо понимать, что сама компания американская, соответственно она пытается причесать все сайты под стандартноамериканские правила. Ну и ещё несколько сложностей на эту тему есть.
3. Про дубликаты уже расписано [в другом вопросе](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7254/178988). На них вполне можно отвечать, но для поиска куда удобнее иметь всё в одном месте, а не раскиданным по куче вопросов. На этот счёт у меня тоже есть идеи, но SO их никогда не реализиует (((

Comment: Я бы послушал про идеи.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica, вкратце - делить сайт на поддомены (как минимум meta, cases, faq [впрочем, faq переименовать]). И делить механизм  одубликачивания - с cases на faq позволяет отвечать на вопрос, с cases на cases - нет, при этом можно одновременно назначать несколько целевых вопросов с каждого сайта, возможно как упорядоченный список. Возможно, делить на большее число (в духе basics, guides, hw).

Comment: Да, точно не будут реализовывать (:

Answer (score 0):

Вообще глубоко ошибочно разделять "бездуховный запад" и "высокодуховный русский (православный/исламский/туркменский/чучхейский...) мир". Все мы произошли от обезьян и в фундаменте имеем одну и ту же человеческую природу, в которой намешано многого, и благородного и отталкивающего.

Большинство здесь вполне адекватные люди с уровнем интеллекта выше среднего, особой ненависти к новичкам, в массе своей, никто не испытывает, тоже самое можно сказать и про англоязычный сектор. А вопрос о непреодолимом противоречии культур оставим на совести тв пропаганды и различных вечерних м., не стоит переносить этот "культурный план" ещё и сюда, здесь обитают люди, в основном, немного другого уровня.